# How to use same Models in different Modules in Laminas Framework (or Zend Framework 3)

Tags: module, zend-framework, model, frameworks, laminas

I am working on implementing Laminas Framework within a project that has a public marketing area, a private members area, an administration area. I would like to create be able to split the controllers and views into modules (one for the members area, one for the public marketing area, one for the admin area but I need to be able to point each module to the same model's since all three components work on the same database and on the same business objects.

**How to use same Models in different Modules in Laminas Framework (or Zend Framework 3)?**

Answer (score 0):

### Using the same entities / data objects

Easy to implement. Just write a single entity / data object and use it in all three (public, member, admin) environments. There is absolutely no need to code models for every environment. The access to these models can be controlled via an access control system. Always provided you have authentication in your system.

### Access control

Since public, members and admins can be seen as roles in your environment, one possible solution could be the [laminas role based access control](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-permissions-rbac/intro/) (rbac).

With rbac many identities can have many roles. Many roles can have many permissions which grant access to a certain models. Even further you can have dynamic assertions if two identities have the same permissions but identity A should not access the data of identity B.

A ready to use implementation can be seen in https://github.com/LM-Commons/LmcRbacMvc.